# Nontransitive dice: the least number of faces?

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

Here is an introduction to [nontransitive dice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nontransitive_dice). The question is: given $n$-player with a $m$-sided dice each one, the what is the minimum of $m$ for a fixed $n$ to produce nontransitivity?

Here is some related posts:

[What is the most extreme set 4 or 5 nontransitive n-sided dice?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/119867/what-is-the-most-extreme-set-4-or-5-nontransitive-n-sided-dice)

[What is the most unfair set of three nontransitive dice?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260072/what-is-the-most-unfair-set-of-three-nontransitive-dice)

[How far can probability intransitivity be stretched?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57338/how-far-can-probability-intransitivity-be-stretched?rq=1)

Comment: $m=3$ for $n=3$, for example, the three dices are {1,5,9}, {2,6,7},{3,4,8}.

Comment: What is $n$? The number of dice? How nontransitive must they be?

Comment: @WillSawin Yeah $n$ is the number of dice.

Comment: What about the second question? There are many large nontransitive arrangements that are not nontransitive in an interesting way. For instance, take lots of small perturbations of your dice: `$\{1.01,5.02,8.99\}$` and so on. This will give a large number of nontransitive dice for $m=3$.  But this doesn't seem like the right case to consider.

Comment: @WillSawin It is a cool idea! We can always to do this perturbation, but the nontransitivity is only related to the order of the numbers but not what they exactly are.