# Nontransitive dice

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability

In the wikipedia article  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nontransitive_dice  it is claimed that " The set of nontransitive dice were investigated by the Latvian computer scientist and mathematician Rusins Freivalds. He showed that if there is a set of $n$ dice, and each die beats the next with probability $p$, then $p$ can be arbitrarily close (but not equal) to 3/4 = 0.75 when $n$ goes to infinity. "  but no reference is given, and a search on google scholar gives nothing.  Does anybody know a reference for this claimed result?

The following (with its answers) is possibly related:   [What is the most extreme set 4 or 5 nontransitive n-sided dice?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/119867/what-is-the-most-extreme-set-4-or-5-nontransitive-n-sided-dice)

Comment: In the talk page of the Wikipedia page, somebody refers to [this](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2974903?seq=3) and [this](http://yadda.icm.edu.pl/yadda/element/bwmeta1.element.desklight-fbdc58ca-256f-459b-bfbe-051fd7e37be4/c/zm8_2_05.pdf) paper. Did you check these?

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57338/how-far-can-probability-intransitivity-be-stretched

Comment: Have you followed up on the comments the last six years, kjetil?